# How do you debug SPI connected devices?

Tags: arduino-nano, spi, rf

EDIT: Changed the title to better express what I'm after.

I've been dabbling in connecting two Arduino Nano 3's with the RFM69HCW breakout for the past 5 days.. but got nowhere.

I've followed the official [hookup guide](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/rfm69hcw-hookup-guide) at first, after that didn't work, I've tried the code samples from a Adafruit post, and still nothing.

By 'nothing', I mean that I compiled and uploaded the code to two separate Arduinos that are literally 5cm apart, tried sending messages, broadcasting messages.. etc. but without any success.

Here they are - on two breadboards, but the layout and connections are symmetrical:

[image: Layout picture]
Yeah, the bottom one is quite confusing to look at because of the wires, but I lent most of them to friends - so I had to improvise.

To clarify the picture, I connected the Arduino as follows:

- D2 -> INT(Interrupt)
- D10 -> SS
- D11 -> MISO
- D12 -> MOSI
- D13 -> C(Clock)

One of the codes that I tried: (This is from the official guide, but modified slightly)

```cpp
#include <RFM69.h>
#include <SPI.h>

#define NETWORKID     0
#define MYNODEID      1 //2 For the other Arduino
#define TONODEID      255

#define FREQUENCY     RF69_915MHZ

#define ENCRYPT       false // Set to "true" to use encryption
#define ENCRYPTKEY    "TOPSECRETPASSWRD" // Use the same 16-byte key on all nodes

#define USEACK        true // Request ACKs or not

RFM69 radio;

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.print("Node ");
  Serial.print(MYNODEID,DEC);
  Serial.println(" ready");  

  radio.initialize(FREQUENCY, MYNODEID, NETWORKID);
  radio.setHighPower();
}

void loop()
{
  static char sendbuffer[62];
  static int sendlength = 0;

  if (Serial.available() > 0)
  {
    char input = Serial.read();

    if (input != '\r')
    {
      sendbuffer[sendlength] = input;
      sendlength++;
    }

    if ((input == '\r') || (sendlength == 61))
    {
      Serial.print("sending to node ");
      Serial.print(TONODEID, DEC);
      Serial.print(", message [");
      for (byte i = 0; i < sendlength; i++)
        Serial.print(sendbuffer[i]);
      Serial.println("]");

      if (radio.sendWithRetry(TONODEID, sendbuffer, sendlength))
        Serial.println("ACK received!");
      else
        Serial.println("no ACK received");

      sendlength = 0;
    }
  }

  if (radio.receiveDone())
  {
    Serial.print("received from node ");
    Serial.print(radio.SENDERID, DEC);
    Serial.print(", message [");

    for (byte i = 0; i < radio.DATALEN; i++)
      Serial.print((char)radio.DATA[i]);

    Serial.print("], RSSI ");
    Serial.println(radio.RSSI);

    if (radio.ACKRequested())
    {
      radio.sendACK();
      Serial.println("ACK sent");
    }
  }
}
```

Notes:
Everything is powered by a 5V 2A brick - the RFM69 modules are receiving a stepped down 3.3V from those small thingies connecting two separate breadboard power rails.

Also... I don't have any 915MHz antennas, so I used some 433MHz ones that I had laying around - I'm going to get correct ones later, but right now, for testing them 5cm apart it should be good enough..?

P.S.: I HATE when stuff doesn't have status LEDs, I could really use some on the radio modules.

Comment: You want to get yourself a cheap USB logic analyser (you can pick them up on places like eBay, DX, Ali, etc for about $6) so you can see what is actually happening on the SPI bus.

Comment: @Majenko Oh yeah, I could do that - probably good in the long run when I will do more complex stuff later on. I'm just curious if anyone could spot any mistakes with my setup, because I have no idea what to do until I get a analyser.

Comment: Have your code read and print key registers from the part to verify that the SPI is working.  You'll need to look into the library internals to do this.

Comment: I'll look into that, luckily the library has all of the registers defined in RFM69registers.h header. Thanks for the suggestion :)

Comment: Did you miss this in the hookup guide: IMPORTANT! Do not power your RFM69 with 5V or connect the data lines directly to a 5V microprocessor. Doing so will damage the device.

Comment: Huh, now I feel kinda stupid. I didn't realise that.. and I KNOW that the logic pins are indeed 5V on the Arduinos that I own... welp.. gonna get some 3.3V (like a... LC33) voltage regulators and hope that those things still work.

Comment: Unless I can do a resistor voltage divider - though I don't see the current (for logic pins) specified anywhere in the datasheets.